# Is there a cheat to unlock all gadgets from the start?

Tags: cheats, batman-arkham-origins

When I use [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nnzR7aonTPY), I only get the first level of gadgets. How do I unlock the rest?

```
BmInput

[Engine.PlayerInput]
.Bindings=(Name="f1", Command="start batentry?Movie=Ep1_0010_Ep1_0130_Ep1_0210?StreamMovie?Area=Prison,Prison_C1?Chapters=1,Y1?Flags=Chapter1_Start?Abilities=Batman_SmokePellets,Batman_RemoteClaw,Batman_WeaponDisruptor,Batman_ShockGloves,Batman_GlueGrenade,Batman_SonicBatarang,Batman_SonicBatarangShock,Batman_BladeCounter,Batman_RemoteClawVantagePointThug,Batman_ConcussionDetonator,Batman_ConcussionDetonatorDuration,Batman_MeleeArmor1,Batman_BallisticArmor1,Batman_MultiTargetBatarangDouble,Batman_MultiTargetBatarangTripple?CreateSave")
```

Comment: Not a solution, since it comes with downsides, but if you cannot find anything, an option is to find a New Game Plus save and load that.  New Game Plus gets access to unlocked gadgets, but has many enhancements to difficulty, also.

Answer (score 1):

I dont know about cheats but there is a way to gain a lot of XP and use it to purchase all the upgrades. To get 120,000 XP in 15 minutes and be able to buy all upgrades at the beginning of the game, go to Burnley. Go to the indicated [location](http://www.cheatcc.com/images/batman_arkham_origins_infinite_xp_location.jpg) on the rooftop, and let the enemy kill you so you are saved at this location.

When you spawn after dying, use the grappling hook to go back to the rooftop, and silent takedown the first three enemies. Then, silent takedown the fourth enemy with a Knockout Smash to get a total of 8,000 XP. After getting the XP and the "Saving..." icon disappears at the bottom of the screen, pause the game and select "Restart" to start from the last checkpoint.

Repeat this process as many times as desired.
There is a video representation of this method below:

<sub>0:00 / 3:32 Batman Arkham Origins - Unlimited XP/All Upgrades 120,000xp 15 Minutes</sub>

Comment: Informative, but the user is specifically asking for a cheat to unlock the gadgets at the start of the game. Having an infinite pool of experience effectively gives you free access to the gadgets, but only as they become available.